# why does $\frac{d}{dx} log_b(x)$ not = $\frac{lnb}{x}$?

Tags: logarithms, implicit-differentiation

I know that $log_b(x) = \frac{lnx}{lnb}$, and that differentiating
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{lnx}{lnb}) = \frac{1}{lnb}\frac{d}{dx}(lnx)=\frac{1}{xlnb}$$,
so where is my mistake when I do it this way:
$$y=log_b(x); b^y = x$$
, so with implicit differentiation
$$\frac{b^y}{lnb} \frac{dy}{dx}=1;  \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{lnb}{b^y}$$
and substitution gives
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{lnb}{b^{log_b(x)}}=\frac{lnb}{x}$$
??? This is not the same answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivative of $b^y$ respect to $x$ is $y'b^y\ln b$

Comment: Okay... why is that different from $\frac{d}{dx}b^x=\frac{b^x}{lnb}$?

Comment: Ahh. My calculus teacher gave us the wrong formula for some reason. Thanks!